# Pushing space bar on file different than a pdf - Fedora

Tags: fedora

Outside of topic/Could be related: I am on Fedora 25. I used to have a problem where if I left my computer alone for too long and I moved the mouse too fast when I came back it would crash. That hasn't happened in a long time so I am sure an update fixed that bug - mentioning in case it's slightly related.

Actual question:
I usually press space bar on pdfs to get a preview of them, my work requires lots of them and it's faster that way. From time to time I will fuck up and press space bar on a `.xml`, `.doc` or something else, and my system freezes up completely. Waiting hours wont unfreeze it,  `ctr + alt + F2` or `ctrl + alt + F5` won't prompt the terminal either. The only way I have found it to stop is to manually press the power off button. Fedora gives me the message that "complements are missing" when this occurs.

Is there anything I can  install that would make the computer not freeze (doesnt have to show a preview, just not freeze)? Or a file I can create so that fedora ignores spacebars in anything that is not a `.pdf`?

Thanks in advanced to all

Comment: After untangling your question it is clear that you need to solve your root problem i.e. Fedora crashing.  Everything other is irrelevant.

Comment: When the crashing used to happen often (I'd say 3 times a week minimum) I would google the bug and I would find people that had it too but no one had a solution. I am just glad it stopped happening but I agree, I need to find an operating system that doesnt crash.

Comment: I would thoroughly test hardware too. For example, perhaps it is not software, but you have faulty RAM?

Comment: Used `memtester` to test the memory and everything was ok, no errors. Couldnt use `memtest86+` because the folllowing error would pop when doing `memtest-setup`, `ERROR: memtest86+ does not support EFI platforms.`

Comment: Are you saying the computer shouldn't freeze if I push space bar on a file different than a `pdf`? Does that occur to any of you?

Comment: My Fedora 27 doesn't freeze (25 is end of life btw) but the "sushi" component which is responsible for these previews indeed crashes on most, if not all, text files. (Works fine on PDFs.) Might be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-sushi/+bug/1675156

Answer (score 1):

I cannot guarantee that it will fix your problem but I would strongly recommend to update to Fedora 26 or 27 for these reasons:

1. Fedora 25 is [end of life](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life?rd=EOL) so there won't be any fixes for your system any more and you can't report this as a bug. (Staying on 25 is also a security risk.)
2. I guess your "gjs" package is below version 1.48.4 (have a look at `sudo dnf info gjs`) and upgrading to F26 will bring it up to 1.48.7 which [fixes a similar bug on manjaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/gnome-sushi-3-24-crashes-on-wayland/26026/4).
3. If you confirm that your problem still exists on a supported Fedora release, more people might be able to reproduce it on their machine and interested in fixing it. (And you can and should report it as a bug!)